# JS - onkeyup (dynamic calculation)

Tags: onkeyup

A very simple table, one cell takes a number and the second one (read-only) 
 displays on-the-fly the double of that number. But, something does not work. Nothing happens:

html:

```
<td><input type="text" id="qantity" name="qantity" onkeyup="getValues()" 
class="number" value="" autofocus placeholder="0" 
onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" 
onblur="this.placeholder = '0'" 
onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
</input></td>
<td id="total" name="total" class="right">0.00</td>
```

js:

```
<script>
function getValues(){
var var_qantity = Number(document.getElementById("qantity").value);
var var_total = var_qantity * 2;
document.getElementById("total").value = var_total;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace
`document.getElementById("priceOriginal").value = var_total;`
with
`document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = var_total;`

Now the doubled value will be visible as soon as the number is typed in the textbox.

If you need additional functionality, please be a bit specific.

Hope this helps.